# most of the year vs most of the times of the year vs most of the time of the year?

Tags: grammar, phrases, american-english, language-formation

I used to relax for most of the year. Is this grammatically correct or do I have to use another phrases like most of the times of the year?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that.

The expression *time of year* refers to one of the seasons. We can say "I like this time of year." - "I enjoy walking at most times of the year, but not in winter." (not *most of the times*).

*Most of the time of the year* is not idiomatic English.